# How to put two span tags on the same line?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put the name and address on the same line with address way on the right and title on the left. What it is doing is putting the address down a line instead of on the same line as name. How can I fix this? Here is the code:

```
<p>
<span id="name">First Last</span> 
<span id="address">123 Address Rd.</span>
</p>


#name{
font-size:18px;
float:left;
color:white;
padding-top:30px;

}
#address{
float:left;
font-size:12px;
padding-left:400px;
color:white;
width:300px;
}
```

Comment: Why are you floating inlined elements - they will appear on the same line naturally and inorder of precedence... http://blog.4psa.com/wp-content/uploads/block-inline1.png

Comment: Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6rgxba3b/

Comment: THey naturally appear on the same line. Just remove float from your css.

Comment: I am doing it this way because I also have pictures that will be inline with the text but the text needs a padding-top:30px; for the text to be where I want it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<div style="text-align:right;width:100%">
    <span style="float:left">Left text</span>
    Right text
</div>
```

These elements will be displayed on the same line, you can even set the parent's div text-align to left and make the span floating right ! Like

```
<div style="text-align:left;width:100%">
<span style="float:right">Right text</span>
Left text
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply remove the `float:left;` and the texts will line up as expected. See the following code-snippet:

```css
#name{
font-size:18px;
color:blue;
padding-top:30px;

}
#address{
font-size:12px;
padding-left:400px;
color:red;
width:300px;
}
```

```html
<p>
<span id="name">First Last</span> 
<span id="address">123 Address Rd.</span>
</p>
```

If you absolutely need to have the `float:left;`, you can also get the text on the same level by making sure the `top-padding` of the smaller text has the correct offset, i.e. that a smaller font has more `top-padding`. You also need to make sure that the text is aligned to the right:

```css
#name{
font-size:18px;
float:left;
padding-top:30px;
color:red;  
}
#address{
font-size:12px;
padding-top:36px;
float:left;
text-align:right;  
width:300px;
color:red;
}
```

```html
<p>
<span id="name">First Last</span> 
<span id="address">123 Address Rd.</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you float the elements you need to add same line-height and padding to align them in a line.